# Converting relative URL requests to absolute URL request using mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have made use of a simple rewrite rule in my .htaccess file to make my URL's pretty. What was once like this:

```
http://somedomain.com/product-details.php?product=MQ==&hash=123456789
```

Is now this:

```
http://somedomain.com/secure/123456789/MQ==/rings/details/blue-diamond-topaz-ring.php
```

This is all very well, but I have many a PHP file that has all JS and CSS links as relative. Because of the above new pretty URL, these links to JS and CSS are now 5 or 6 directories too deep.

**My Question:** By means of mod_rewrite, is there a way I can make a request for `css/style.css` or `js/somescript.js` rewrite to something like `http://www/somedomain.com/css/style.css` for example?

I have Googled my heart out and done my homework, and while I can find a million references to rewriting URL's, none seem to work in the same manner for requesting such scripts. I tried this but to no avail:

```
RewriteRule ^/css/(.*)$ http://localhost/dev/css/$1 [R=302,L]
```

I assumed that would send ALL requests like `/css/somefile.css` to `http://localhost/dev/css/somefile.css`

Any help or guidance is well and truly appreciated.

---

**UPDATE: Here is the rewrite portion of my .htaccess file:**

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /eterniti-mygate/
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-article-([^-]*)\.php$ /in-the-news.php?action=$1&article=$2 [L]
#rings rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^secure/([^-]*)/([^-]*)/rings/details/([^_]*)\.php$ ring-details.php?product=$2&hash=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ http://localhost/eterniti-mygate/css/$1 [R=302,L]
```

**UPDATE: Here is the log file output for the rewrites**

Please see my log file at https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B-NRfZvE6xi7MmI0N2ZjNzEtYWZlYy00NjJiLWJhMjQtYzAyYzY4ZWIxN2U0&hl=en_GB

It appears to not be rewriting the request from the base, but rather from the virtual directory (eg /secure/ring/details/). I have set the rewriteBase to /eterniti-mygate/ which is a folder on my wamp server root.

Comment: if you add a "/" on your js and css paths like this "/js/foo.js" don't you have automatically the browser sending request starting at the root of the website, without any rewriteRule hacks?

Comment: From my experience with paths, when using '/' or no '/' the path always seems to be relative to the folder I am in when calling scripts in my web pages. One would expect that it references the absolute path from the home directory when using something like /css/... but indeed it is not. I know unix and windows paths are different, but I'd expect the same or similar behavior in such a case.

Comment: @One Stuck Piexl. I'm always using absolute path (e.g. `/images/sprite.png`) when referring to resources from within a page or css file (background image, for example) with no problems at all. Absolute path means absolute from website root -- i.e. they are used by browser on client side not PHP on server side.

Comment: @LazyOne then they are relative not absolute. They are "relative" to the web site root, not "absolute" to the home directory surely? Or have I got my relative and absolutes mixed up ;) ?

Comment: Yes, relative to the root :) I meant that such URL will ALWAYS be the same regardless from which file it was referenced. In any case -- I do not recommend to rewrite paths to CSS files just because it can be done -- only if you have fully tested & working solution, otherwise you will have these quirks.

Answer (score 0):

When using rewriterule remove the leading (back)slash, so try this:

```
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ http://localhost/dev/css/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to make a difference. Do I need to set rewriteBase or anything like that?

Comment: You could try to put a 'RewriteBase /' directive below you Options or RewriteEngine directive yes. Also maybe you could post your whole htaccess file, there might be another way to rewrite the requests

Comment: Still no difference adding the rewriteBase or Options +FollowSymLinks. Updating my answer with htaccess file now. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

This should be useful

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.css
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ http://localhost/dev/css/$1 [L]
```

When a .css file is called, you rewrite (if the file is under css/) to `http://localhost/dev/css/<pathorname>`.

Take care that `<pathorname>` can include subdirectories.
Also the [R=302] might just not be needed. Internal redirection should be enough.

If that does not work, you can see what happens with :

```
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 2
```

(you can push log level to 4 if you still can't understand.)

### ' Edit with the log details

```
Line 20 :  [perdir C:/wamp/www/eterniti-mygate/] add path info postfix: C:/wamp/www/eterniti-mygate/secure -> C:/wamp/www/eterniti-mygate/secure/af192eaa6808acab8947ce59a32f8d17/MQ==/rings/details/css/reset.css
Line 21 :  [perdir C:/wamp/www/eterniti-mygate/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/eterniti-mygate/secure/af192eaa6808acab8947ce59a32f8d17/MQ==/rings/details/css/reset.css -> secure/af192eaa6808acab8947ce59a32f8d17/MQ==/rings/details/css/reset.css
```

We are trying to serve  secure/af192eaa6808acab8947ce59a32f8d17/MQ==/rings/details/css/reset.css

```
'^([^-]*)-article-([^-]*)\.php$'
'^secure/([^-]*)/([^-]*)/rings/details/([^_]*)\.php$'
'^css/(.*)$'
```

Won't match. Knowing that the caret (`^`) means : beginning of the string/URL (`http://mysite.com excluded`), you can't detect something that is not like `css/<something>END` (FYI: `$` means ends of string/URL). Remove it from your rule and it should match `<anything>css/<something>END` and the rule will apply.

Comment: Unfortunately still no luck. This is strange. Adding the RewriteLog "" throws an internal server error. I am using a WAMP setup on Windoze, so I added this as my path: RewriteLog "C:/wamp/logs/rewrite.log" but still a server error.

Comment: Is the rewrite module enabled? Maybe you also need a `RewriteEngine On` directive. In which file are you setting your directive up?

Comment: @M'vy, @One Stuck Piexl `RewriteLogLevel` and `RewriteLog` CANNOT be placed in .htaccess -- only in config files (e.g. httpd.conf, httpd-vhost.conf): http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel

Comment: @LazyOne good guess. Didn't see the `.htaccess` file had been add.

Comment: @LazyOne, thank you for clearing that up. Let me add it to my config file, see if there are any errors and then log them for you. Appreciate every ones assistance.

Comment: Please see link to config file, I do not understand the log, but I can see requests for /secure/css/somefile.css when they really should be requesting from ROOT/css/somefile.css

Comment: I have updated the answer. I think your problem is that your rule is explicitly looking for `http://mysite.com/css/<something>` and your css directories where not directly at the root but inside deeper dirs.

Comment: @M'vy - Many thanks for your help, my CSS files are indeed in the root of the site at domain.com/css so does the above rule apply still? The issue seems to be that I am rewriting the url to some/thing/here and the css is being looked for ar some/thing/here/css when in actual fact it lives at /css ? Driving me nuts!

Comment: No the problem should be your `^` at the beginning of your rewrite rule for css. With `^css/(.*)$` it will never match `secure/af192eaa6808acab8947ce59a32f8d17/MQ==/rings/details/css/reset.css` and then never rewrite anything. Did you try to loose the `^` ?

Comment: @M'vy - I removed the ^ and it works. I used this rule: `RewriteRule css/([^_]*).css$ css/$1.css [L]` but now I see the images referenced in the CSS do not call. Adding an image rule like `RewriteRule images/([^_]*)$ images/$1 [L]` also does not work. I think the best way to settle my dilemma is to add a config file include on all pages and define a BASE_DIR constant referencing the base of the site?

Comment: I would give you all vote up, but I do not have the reputation too. Just so that you know I appreciate all of your help.