# URL Rewrite for relative URLs on localhost

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I just moved my website to a folder (called test) inside the root of my Apache web server and now I am getting 404 errors while the page tries to fetch different resources.
When I looked at the urls - they seem to be pointing to the root of server as they are root relative URLs (as opposed to be pointing to the folder [test] inside the root).

For example: when the index page of my site has a reference to an image like

```
<img src="/images/img-1.jpg" alt="Image 1" />
```

The page when executed, tries to fetch the image from the following url

```
http://localhost/slider-images/img-1.jpg
```

instead of accessing the image from the url

```
http://localhost/slider-images/test/img-1.jpg
```

I have been trying various options like having a ReWriteBase etc, but that doesn't seem to be working!

What works instead is me changing the resource path to be an absolute one, but that is just too much of work for me to do for all the resources!

```
<img src="./images/img-1.jpg" alt="Image 1" />
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

**Update**

A similiar question has been posted earlier, but I don't a response that solved the issue
[Converting relative URL requests to absolute URL request using mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731564/converting-relative-url-requests-to-absolute-url-request-using-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of troubleshooting, I did a workaround which can be used a temp fix.
Posting it here to help those who possibly could be having the same problem.

Simply changed the DocumentRoot in httpd.conf file to point to the sub-directory where I had moved my website files for testing.

Hope this helps those who can make use it this fix.

I would still be really interested to know of a way to address the root-relative URL rewrites via htaccess and hopefully someone here would be able to help.

Thanks!